# WCF Service DataServiceConfiguration namespace conflict

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I am trying to create my first wcf service application. Due to an error in entity framework I was led to install the package Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider 1.0.0-beta2

After this I have the following code for the service:

```
using System.Data.Services.Providers;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Data.Services;
namespace NorthwindService
{
    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class NorthWind : EntityFrameworkDataService<NorthwindEntities>
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {

           config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Orders", EntitySetRights.AllRead
                                          | EntitySetRights.WriteMerge
                                          | EntitySetRights.WriteReplace);
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Order_Details", EntitySetRights.AllRead
                                          | EntitySetRights.AllWrite);
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Customers", EntitySetRights.AllRead);

            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is that I get the error that I have conflict between System.Data.Services and Microsoft.Data.Services. But If i remove the first and i add the second to my uses, I get that Microsoft.Data.Services is unrecognized.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a type alias if you need to disambiguate use of a type that could come from more than one place:

```
using WinTimer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;
using ThreadTimer = System.Threading.Timer;
```

If you have a type that exists in `Microsoft.Data` and `System.Data` and you really need both - create a type alias as shown above.

Comment: The problem is that if I choose Microsoft.Data.Services then it says that the namespace cannot be found

Comment: The type DataServiceConfiguration exists in both Microsoft.Data.Services and in System.Data.Services. This is the error. But If to resolve this I remove System.Data.Services from my uses and I add Microsoft.Data.Services this last one is not recognized, that's why it's puzzling to me

Comment: What happens if you try `public static void InitializeService(System.Data.Services.DataServiceConfiguration config)`?

Comment: I have tried this and it still says there is conflict! Same error as before